# RESTful Web Service: proper request header to specify the end-user's IP

Tags: web-services, http-headers, ip

**Scenario:**

---

End User **A** browses a web site served by **B** that provide contents (to A) by consuming a web service **C**

For logging, statistic and security purposes **B** is expected to communicate to **C** the IP address of **A**

---

**Question:**

---

What is the canonical or recomended way (if any) to do that?

Should the IP be passed in the request body (as one of the parameters of the request) or there is a specific HTTP Header for that ?

May/should I use a custom `X-` HTTP Header ?

I've read about `X-Originating-IP` but is specific for email services while `X-Forwarded-For` is related to proxies so they seem not appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the canonical or recommended way (if any) to do that?

Not sure if there is one.

On initial thought it does make sense to use a `X-` prefix, but that practice has been deprecated (see https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6648). On the other hand, deprecated or not, people do understand that `X-something` is non standard, and if none that they’ve seen they will recognize it as something custom.

If you ask me, known ones like `X-Forwarded-For` or `X-Real-IP` kinda’ get the message across and their meaning is easy to determine. But if you don’t know what to send discuss it with the developers of the C web service and agree on a name (existing one or new).